# Overloading ++ operator and returning pointer int

Tags: c++, overloading

I got an assigment where I got to code a class `Queue`

In here I have to overload the ++ operator so i can increment the size of a dynamic array

my dynamic array is called `queuePtr` and I try to do `queuePtr++` for my h file i have done this

```
int *operator++(int)
int *operator++();
```

But I get a runtime error, so I tried to do some debugging and found out it simply did skip my methodes for my overloading

One of my friends then send me how he did it, and he did it like this

```
Queue &Queue::operator++()
Queue Queue::operator++(int)
```

and then called operator++() inside one of the methodes in the class

But i have seen earlier that the compiler can find out what type it is by it self in main like this-

If i have a class lets call it rclass where i have overloadede the ++ operator like this:

```
rclass rclass:operator++(int)
```

and the main looks like this:

```
main
{
rclass b;
b++;
}
```

Here it can find out by itself that b is a object of rclass and there for should use the overloaded ++ from the class

Why doesnt that work in my assignment?

Hope you understand what I mean, english isn't my native language

Comment: Increment the size of a dynamic array? Do you know how inefficient that is? You can't simply 'add a slot' at the end; you have to destroy your previous array, reallocate a new one with a size of `oldSize + 1`, and then copy all the old elements over. Unless you're talking about incrementing an iterator, which is a completely different story. Other than that, I couldn't understand much of what you're saying.

Comment: no no i know I can't "add a slot" at the end with ++ thats why i am tring to overload the ++ operator so i actually can do it

Comment: This sounds like something from an obfuscated code contest. I think you may have misunderstood the assignment; perhaps you're simply being asked to use `int*` (int pointers) and increment those; no classes or overloading at all (and it makes sense that it would come up when building your own queue)

Comment: Incidentally; the usual memory management pattern for queues and lists is to have a block of memory, a current used size and a maximum size available. When the used size reaches the maximum, the memory block is reallocated (usually to double the size) and the maximum set to the new size. This means you only need log(n) reallocations, which is good because reallocation is *slow*

Comment: This is simply a pratice for overloading as it is something we have just learned about, but yes i do have a maximum size and a current used size available, in my overloaded ++ operator i am deleting the old pointer and making a new one with the new size as mention above i should do. The thing is, in the assignment it says precisely that i have to use the ++ operator if i have to make the pointer bigger

Comment: Well, very strange but if that's the assignment... You should be able to get it working with `void operator++(int){/*do stuff*/}`. Note that that returns void - it doesn't need to, but making a copy of the object when growing the memory is plain silly and you'll never need the return value (you're just using this like a method after all), so void is the most appropriate return. Just put that inside your class like any other method, or declare it in the class and define it outside using `void MyClass::operator++(int){}` like normal.